# What is a timestamp in Linux?

Tags: timestamp

While reading about Linux I got the following:

> touch provides several options, but here is one of interest:
>
> The -t option allows you to set the date and time stamp of the file.
>   To set the time stamp to a specific time:
>
> ```
> $ touch -t 03201600 myfile
> ```
>
> This sets the file, myfile's, time stamp to 4 p.m., March 20th (03 20 1600).

Here, I am not getting the logic behind 03201600 --> 4pm, March 20th.

Comment: That is not what is usually called a Unix timestamp (there's no Linux timestamp, just a Unix one). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822821/what-is-a-unix-timestamp-and-why-use-it for more info Unix timestamps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The output you posted explains the format by breaking apart the numbers as (03 20 1600):

```
03 - March
20 - 20th
1600 - 4:00 PM (24-hour clock, where 0000 is midnight)
```

Comment: is it that 1hr = 100 from 12:00 AM

Answer (score 23):

Welcome to Linux! You probably read that `touch` text you quoted in your question from a guide or a book.

In Linux, almost every command has a "manual" that explains its options. You can view the manual page of any command by executing `man <command>` on a Linux machine.

So, from the command `man touch`:

```
   -t STAMP
          use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
```

So, your example:

```
-t 03201600

#Breaking it down:

-t    03     20     16      00
-t    MM     DD     hh      mm
-t   month   day   hours  minutes
```

So March 20th, 4pm (24-hour format).

If you don't have access to a Linux machine, you can view these `man` pages online from here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi. The `man` page for the command `touch` is found here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch

Comment: thanx @Alaa Ali, I totally got it

Answer (score 5):

According to [`man touch`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/touch.1.html):

```
   -t STAMP
          use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
```

So, your timestamp can be translated to `DD/MM hh:mm`: 20/03 16:00.

Answer (score 1):

> A timestamp is the current time of an event that is recorded by a
>   computer.
>
> Timestamps are employed extensively within computers and over networks
>   for various types of synchronization. For example, they are assigned
>   to packets in some network protocols in order to facilitate the
>   reassembly of the data (e.g., human speech) in the proper sequence by
>   the receiving host (i.e., computer). Also, they are used by database
>   management systems (DBMS) to determine the transaction order in the
>   event of a system failure (e.g., a computer crash caused by a loss of
>   electrical power or disk failure).
>
> Timestamps are also routinely used to provide information about files,
>   including when they were created and last accessed or modified. This
>   information is included in the inode, which is a data structure on a
>   file system on a Unix-like operating system that stores all the
>   information about a file except its name and its actual data.
>
> Another important application is events that are recorded in system
>   log files. The timestamps in such files can be extremely useful for
>   monitoring system security and for forensic purposes.
>
> The time as recorded by timestamps can be measured in terms of the
>   time of day or relative to some starting point. And it is measured
>   with high precision in small fractions of a second.
>
> The accuracy of the time is maintained through a variety of
>   mechanisms, including the high-precision clocks built into computers
>   and the network time protocol (NTP). NTP uses coordinated universal
>   time (UTC) to synchronize computer clock times to a millisecond (and
>   sometimes to a fraction of a millisecond) and uses UDP (user datagram
>   protocol), one of the core Internet protocols, as its transport
>   mechanism.<sup>[Timestamp](http://www.linfo.org/timestamp.html)</sup>

Click [here](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) to convert

Comment: thanx @Mitch , one more question is it somewhat related to NTP(network time protocol)?

Comment: Yes it uses that to calculate time.

Comment: Although in this case, `touch` doesn't actually use a Unix timestamp.

Comment: The OP's question is "What is a timestamp in Linux?" and I explained what timestamp is.